# Check if a session is active with Session ID - Laravel

Tags: session, laravel-5

I am working in a project in which i am in need to do the following

- Save session id, as soon as a user logs in with user's db row
- When same user tries to log into some other computer, i should check if the session id in user's db row is active or not and do certain operations based on the session active state

Please suggest if there is any function to check session state with session id in laravel.
EDIT :

Consider following terms :

```
Session 1 > First login done by user in a computer
Session 2 > User tries to login in another computer
```

I tried to see if i can get session's variable with session id by using following function when user tries to log into another computer

```
$request->session()->setId("SESSION_ID");
```

But doing so, only the session id of Session 2 changes, but i could not get data related to Session 1.

Comment: can you edit the question to show what have you tried?

Comment: I tried searching the web to see if there is any ways to do it.. but i could not find any answers about this..

Comment: @Antz_shrek Updated my answer

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? Id also like to know if there is a way to check if a given session is still active? something like 

session()->isActive(someId);  would be nice

Answer (score 1):

if you have the SESSION_ID, you can use the getHandler () function to get the laravel's session. The code would be:

```
$session = \Session::getHandler()->read(SESSION_ID);
```

If $session is equals to null or empty, it means that the laravel's session don't exist or is expired, otherwise it means that the session is still active